# Print a console "picture" using recursion

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop, recursion

I'm having some trouble printing the following picture.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1       (16 times)
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2           (12 times)
        3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3                (8 times)
            4 4 4 4                    (4 times)
        3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3                (8 times)
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2           (12 times)
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1       (16 times)
```

It's easy for me to implement an iterative algorithm, but I have to use recursion. I've written the following code (C++) that seems to do the job.

```
void print(int n, int current)
{
    int offset = (n / 2) * (current - 1);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < offset; i++)
        printf("  ");
    for (i = 1; i <= (n - current + 1) * n; i++)
        printf("%i ", current);
    printf("\n");
}

void picture(int n, int current)
{
    if (current < n) {  
        print(n, current);
        picture(n, current + 1);
        print(n, current);
    }
    else
        if (current == n)
            print(n, current);
}


int main()
{
int n;
    input: printf("Enter n --> ");
    scanf_s("%i", &n);
    if ((n < 1) || (n > 9) || (n % 2 == 1)) {
        printf("ERROR: n must be an even decimal digit!\n");
        goto input;
    }

    picture(n, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder whether there is a simpler way to write the recursive function here.

**Update**: I've tried to identify the recursion in a much simpler problem of printing the "pyramid":

```
1
2 2
3 3 3 
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

The function `pyram` receives two parameters: the maximum number `n` (5 in our case) and the current number `k`. `k` is printed `k` times, then `pyram` is called with the parameters `n` and `k + 1`. This happens only when `k <= n`.

```
void pyram(int n, int k)
{
    if (k <= n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            printf("%i ", k);
        printf("\n");
        pyram(n, k + 1);
    }
}
```

I've written my solution to the original problem in a similar manner.

Comment: Perhaps it's time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: that wrong line is acutally not needed, as `current` will never be bigger than `n`, still you should remove it. For working code you can get feedback at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but before you should make sure that it is really working ;)

Comment: @drescherjm, yes, that was a typo. I've corrected it, thanks.

Comment: If this code works (you say that it "seems to"), then you might consider posting it for review on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Note that cross-posting is frowned upon within the Stack Exchange network, so if you do, you'll need to delete this question.

Comment: Recursion is great when you can break up your problem in one simple part and one complex part. Then just simplify the complex one step by step until you reach the simple solution.

Comment: I love this explanation on recursion: "Recursion - See recursion"

Comment: @JoachimNilsson, the code in my question is actually mine. The textbook doesn't have any solutions. Perhaps I should have stated this explicitly.

Comment: @AlexKonrad Great job then, try to apply my previous comment on simplifying the problem. Search for some examples then perhaps you will find it.

Comment: @JoachimNilsson, I've tried to solve a similar recursive problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use static variables in the recursive function. In this case the function declaration will look simpler and you will not need an auxiliary function.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display_pattern( unsigned int n )
{
    const unsigned int FACTOR = 4;
    static unsigned int value = 1;
    static int indent = 1;

    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "%*u", indent, value );
        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < FACTOR * n; i++ ) printf( " %u", value );
        putchar( '\n' );

        indent += FACTOR;
        ++value;

        display_pattern( --n );

        indent -= FACTOR;
        --value;
    }

    if ( n++ )
    {
        printf( "%*u", indent, value );
        for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < FACTOR * n; i++ ) printf( " %u", value );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number less than %u (0 - exit): ", N );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        if ( !( n < N ) ) n = N - 1;

        putchar( '\n' );
        display_pattern( n );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output can look like

```
Enter a non-negative number less than 10 (0 - exit): 10

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
        3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
            4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
                5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
                    6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
                        7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
                            8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
                                9 9 9 9
                            8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
                        7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
                    6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
                5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
            4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
        3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number less than 10 (0 - exit): 4

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
        3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
            4 4 4 4
        3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
    2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Enter a non-negative number less than 10 (0 - exit): 0
```

As for the function `pyram` then it can look like

```
void display_triangle( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        display_triangle( n - 1 );
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%u ", n );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```